# SQL Stored Procedure running exec work running with sp_executesql blank

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure when run and test in studio work ok.

When run in C# blank - when profiler and check what # send and try that in studio error

[Replace image with formatted text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGARj.jpg)

```
Worked
    exec spGetReportDepartSalesALL  @Storeid = '1001',  @lodate = '07/28/2021 00:00:00', @hidate =  '07/28/2021 23:59:59', @Stationid = '', @departlist = '', @cashierid = '1001003'
  
Blank  
    exec sp_executesql N'exec spGetReportDepartSalesALL  @StoreID, @lodate,@hidate,@Stationid,@departlist,@cashierid,@cashierid varchar(100),@departlist nvarchar(6),@Stationid char(2),
    @StoreID char(4),@lodate char(22),@hidate char(22)', @cashierid='1001003', @departlist='', @Stationid='01', @StoreID='1001', @lodate='07/28/2021 00:00:00',
    @hidate='07/28/2021 23:59:59'
```

the sp code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetReportDepartSalesALL]   
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here  
   @storeId varchar(10),  
 @lodate datetime,  
 @hidate datetime,  
 @Stationid varchar(10),  
 @cashierid nvarchar(MAX),  
 @departlist nvarchar(MAX)   
AS  
BEGIN  
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from  
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.  
 SET NOCOUNT ON;  
  
SELECT  
Departments.Dept_ID,   
Departments.Description,  
Inventory.ItemNum,  
Inventory.ItemName,  
Inventory.Vendor_Part_Num,  
Inventory.Location, SUM(Invoice_Itemized.Quantity) ASQuantity,  
SUM(Invoice_Itemized.Quantity * (Invoice_Itemized.PricePer+Invoice_Itemized.GC_Sold+Invoice_Itemized.Liability)) * (1 - Invoice_Totals.Discount) AS TotalPrice   
FROM   
Invoice_Totals INNER JOIN ((Departments INNER JOIN Inventory ON (Departments.Store_ID = Inventory.Store_ID) AND (Departments.Dept_ID = Inventory.Dept_ID))   
INNER JOIN Invoice_Itemized ON   
(Inventory.Store_ID = Invoice_Itemized.Store_ID) AND (Inventory.ItemNum = Invoice_Itemized.ItemNum)) ON (Invoice_Totals.Store_ID = Invoice_Itemized.Store_ID) AND (Invoice_Totals.Invoice_Number =   
Invoice_Itemized.Invoice_Number)   
WHERE   
Invoice_Totals.DateTime BETWEEN ( @lodate) AND (@hidate)   
AND Invoice_Totals.Status = 'C' AND Invoice_Itemized.ItemNum <>   
'GIFT_C' AND Invoice_Totals.Store_ID = @storeId AND Inventory.Store_ID = @storeId  and     
(@Stationid='' OR station_id=@Stationid) and   
  
(@departlist='' OR Departments.Dept_ID in (Select value FROM  STRING_SPLIT(@departlist,','))) and  
(@cashierid='' OR Invoice_Totals.Cashier_ID in  (Select value FROM  STRING_SPLIT(@cashierid,',')))   
  
GROUP BY Departments.Dept_ID, Departments.Description, Inventory.ItemNum, Inventory.ItemName, Inventory.Vendor_Part_Num, Inventory.Location,  Invoice_Totals.Cashier_ID,  
Invoice_Totals.Discount,Invoice_Totals.Cashier_ID   
ORDER BY Departments.Dept_ID  
   
END
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: `@hidate='07/28/2021 23:59:59'` Use an **exclusive** upper boundary. The datetime datatype is more precise than this and you run the very small risk that you ignore values that should be included. It's a bad habit. `@hidate char(22)'` No - it's a datetime. You have much to learn about dynamic sql.

Comment: ok Dale. Thank for the advice

Comment: Simple answer: the second version is passing parameters by position, not by name. To pass by name you need `@StoreID = @StoreID`. Why would you ever use the second version anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong order of parameters (procedure declaration vs sp_executesql).

Syntax is `sp_executesql N'statment', [ {parameters definitions}, {parameters values} ]`

Parameter definitions have to be in a separate parameter.

```
 exec sp_executesql N'exec spGetReportDepartSalesALL  @StoreID = @StoreID, @lodate = @lodate, @hidate = @hidate, @Stationid = @Stationid, @departlist = @departlist, @cashierid = @cashierid',
    N'@cashierid varchar(100),@departlist nvarchar(6),@Stationid char(2), @StoreID char(4),@lodate char(22),@hidate char(22)',
    @cashierid='1001003', @departlist='', @Stationid='01', @StoreID='1001', @lodate='07/28/2021 00:00:00', @hidate='07/28/2021 23:59:59'
```

SQL statement can be simplified as follows. In simplified version the order of parameters is important and has to be same as in procedure declaration.

```
 exec sp_executesql N'exec spGetReportDepartSalesALL  @StoreID, @lodate, @hidate, @Stationid, @cashierid, @departlist',
    N'@cashierid varchar(100),@departlist nvarchar(6),@Stationid char(2), @StoreID char(4),@lodate char(22),@hidate char(22)',
    @cashierid='1001003', @departlist='', @Stationid='01', @StoreID='1001', @lodate='07/28/2021 00:00:00', @hidate='07/28/2021 23:59:59'
```

Comment: i added the sp code.  the problem i having if i add value to cashierid and stationid it blank with using the sp_executesql but the other one it work with no problem.

Comment: @CoolTech changed answer according to changed question. Either use sql with `@StoreID = @StoreID` or change order of parameters according to procedure declaration.

Answer (score 0):

the order was set wrong that why there was error.

thank for the help.